# How to plot coordinates onto a 3D image and display it

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, plot

I have a 3D image as a layered tif file, its a binary volume showing blobs at specific locations. I also have an output from a prediction algorithm that predicts the coordinates of the said blobs in the image.

Up until now I have been reading in and writing the tif files using `imageio.volread` and `imageio.volwrite` but I want to see how accurately the prediction algorithm is working so I would like to plot the coordinates onto the image. The coordinates are `[x,y,z]` values where the number of rows equal the number of blobs.

I searched and found out that there is no easy way for python to achieve this in 3D. taking guidance from here: https://www.raddq.com/dicom-processing-segmentation-visualization-in-python/,  what I did attempt was to utilize `skimage.measure.marching_cubes` to convert the image into a 2D surface mesh so that it can be plotted using `matplotlib` and then use that to plot my image.

```
def make_mesh(image):
    print('Transposing surface')
    p = image.transpose(2, 1, 0)

    print('Calculating surface')
    verts, faces, norm, val = measure.marching_cubes_lewiner(p, allow_degenerate=True)
    return verts, faces

def plt_3d(verts, faces):
    print('Drawing')
    x, y, z = zip(*verts)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    # Fancy indexing: `verts[faces]` to generate a collection of triangles
    mesh = Poly3DCollection(verts[faces], linewidths=0.05, alpha=1)
    face_color = [1, 1, 0.9]
    mesh.set_facecolor(face_color)
    ax.add_collection3d(mesh)

    ax.set_xlim(0, max(x))
    ax.set_ylim(0, max(y))
    ax.set_zlim(0, max(z))
    # ax.set_axis_bgcolor((0.7, 0.7, 0.7))
    plt.show()

img_gt = io.volread(gt_path)
v, f = make_mesh(img_gt)
plt_3d(v, f)
```

The image is a `[21,512,1024]` and consists of 5 'blobs', but the `plot_3d` generates the following:

[image]

am I not using the `marching_cubes` function properly? Why is the plot so distorted? The original blobs are clean spheres, not stretched at all.

Furthermore if this is the only way to plot my image, how would I plot my `[x,y,z]` coordinates on top of this?

Comment: It looks like the "blobs" are indeed spherical *in data coordinates*. They might look distorted due to the very unequal aspect of the plot's limits.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for replying. Can you suggest a way to fix this please and how I would be able to plot my ``[x,y,z]`` coordinates ontop of this? Thanks

Comment: You set the limits yourself via `ax.set_xlim` etc. Use equal spaced numbers for all three axes.